# Linear-gradient in navigation is not displaying

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, linear-gradients

I have created a navigation with a hidden horizontal scrollbar, as shown in the code snippet below. I wish to add a linear gradient to the end of the navbar from transparent to white, to show there is more links to see.

I have added it in as a pseudo ::after element, but I dont know why its not working. I thought it might of been a z-index thing, but that didn't work.

Anyone got a better idea of why?

Thanks

```css
.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.nav-scroller .nav-link {
  padding-top: 0.75rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.nav-scroller .nav::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(white, 0), rgba(white, 1));
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="nav-scroller py-1 mb-2">
    <nav class="nav d-flex justify-content-between">
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">World</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">U.S.</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Technology</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Design</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Culture</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Business</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Politics</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Opinion</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Science</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Health</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Style</a>
      <a class="p-2 text-muted" href="#">Travel</a>
    </nav>
    <div class="next"><span class="">></span></div>
    <div class="prev"><span class=""></span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="jumbotron-fluid jumbotron">
    <div class="col-lg-10 text-center">
      <div class="lead">
        <h1>Horizontal Navigation Scroller</h1>
        <small>Simple and elegant solution with CSS</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the background property correctly i mean the linear gradient property correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think you can use `rgba()` like that. You need to do something like:

```
rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)    rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)
```

Secondly when I look at your problem more closely, the first thing that came to my mind is that what you want could be achieved by `carousel`. What you're doing here would be complicated because, for example, I don't know how you're going to wire up `prev` and `next` navigation button to scroll left and right.

Instead, I try to implement what you want using a plugin called `OwlCarousel`: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/126019/

This might not be what you want, but I just want to give you another option implemented by javascript libraries out there.

Comment: my question was regarding the linear gradient.

Comment: ah that makes sense with the rgba's. I will try that.